# Authorization error on gdata Spreadsheet

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gdata

Was using gdata to update a spreadsheet file on my drive using python on appengine. Everything works fine until recently, the code started encountering error.

```
    import webapp2
import gdata.spreadsheet.text_db
from google.appengine.api import mail


client = gdata.spreadsheet.text_db.DatabaseClient(username='mail@gmail.com', password='passsword')

class createSurvey(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        db = client.CreateDatabase("Project")// this line started to show the error below.
```

.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    db = client.CreateDatabase("Project")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\gdata\spreadsheet\text_db.py", line 146, in CreateDatabase
    db_entry = self.__docs_client.UploadSpreadsheet(virtual_media_source, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\atom\__init__.py", line 1475, in deprecated_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\gdata\docs\service.py", line 466, in UploadSpreadsheet
    folder_or_uri=folder_or_uri)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\gdata\docs\service.py", line 161, in _UploadFile
    converter=gdata.docs.DocumentListEntryFromString)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\gdata\service.py", line 1236, in Post
    media_source=media_source, converter=converter)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\gdata\service.py", line 1358, in PostOrPut
    'reason': server_response.reason, 'body': result_body}
RequestError: {'status': 401, 'body': '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Authorization required</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">\n<H1>Authorization required</H1>\n<H2>Error 401</H2>\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n', 'reason': 'Authorization required'}
```

Initially thought  it was the restriction on the file but i have made it open and it still didn't work. How can i fix this .

Comment: Have you seen this? https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3851#c2 It's not a good practice to have your credentials in the source code this way anyway.

Comment: Yea, i have. Did it this way for the sake of this question.

Comment: So doesn't that answer your question? Or does it not work with oAuth2 either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google stopped allowing such method of authentication. Developers have to create credentials on google console. [see this for more help](http://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html#troubleshooting) and if you are using Google Data Protocol for to access help use spreadsheet as db like i was trying to do, [This](http://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) should also be of help.